# working with complex data type in redis

Tags: java, graph, redis, redisgraph

I'm trying to store nodes of a graph  in redis.
My node is of type  HashMap(String fromNode, HashMap(String toNode,Integer weight) )
How do I store such data structure in redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment RedisGraph requires UUID, please make sure UUID lib is installed on your system, to install run: apt-get install uuid-dev

Please let me know if resolved, Thank you.

Comment: I have added my comment on repo,
After installing apt-get install uuid-dev and then cmake ., when I try to run
redis-server --loadmodule <my-path >/src/libmodule.so 
I get following error
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 2
>>> 'loadmodule "/<my directory>/redis-graph/src/libmodule.so"'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

Comment: So following configuration worked for me :
1. updated Redis server to v4 on Ubuntu
2. passed the complete path of redis-server when using --loadmodule flag.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in storing the data, any serialization to a String would do. If you want to query the data, first define the queries and then choose the data structure.

Intuitively, without familiarity with your requirements, I'd use a Sorted Set per fromNode, in which each member is a toNode and the score is set to its weight. That said, a graph implementation is far from trivial. As an alternative, check [`Redis Graph`](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redis-module-graph) - a Redis v4 module that implements a graph database with a Cypher-like querying language.

Comment: I'm trying to build redis-graph from https://github.com/swilly22/redis-graph using command: cmake . && make module, but I get error :
3 warnings generated.
[ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/module.dir/rmutil/util.o
[ 97%] Building C object CMakeFiles/module.dir/rmutil/strings.o
[100%] Linking C shared module libmodule.so

Comment: Please make an issue report at the repository

Comment: This appears to be yours too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988661/error-when-building-redis-graph